# Read CSV File into Pandas Dataframe with Chunking Resulting in a Single Target Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to read a large 4GB file as csv in Pandas into a dataframe. Here is my current code:

```
source_data_df = pd.read_csv(temp_file, skipinitialspace=True, dtype=str, na_values=['N.A.'])
```

It fails due to out of memory error.

I know I can use chunksize Pandas option to reduce memory utilization and process data in chunks before saving to disk. I can't figure out how to create the resulting single dataframe with all the data from csv file from the chunks before saving it to disk. I need help finishing this code to create this final dataframe. Could someone help?

```
chunksize = 10000000
with pd.read_csv(temp_file, skipinitialspace=True, dtype=str, na_values=['N.A.'], chunksize=chunksize) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        process(chunk)
```

Alternatively, can the processed chunks be appended to a single target file on disk? How would the above code look then?

Also, need a recommendation on the optimal chunksize for 3 GB file, does chunksize represent the size of a chunk in bytes? What would it be for say 500 MB chunks?

What units the chunksize is measured in? I assumed it is bytes, can someone confirm?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "I can't figure out how to create the resulting single dataframe with all the data from csv file from the chunks before saving it to disk." So you want to have the entire dataframe in memory at some point? Doesn't this defeat the purpose of loading it in chunks? If you don't have enough memory to load all the data at once, you won't have enough memory to join all the chunks in one dataframe.

Comment: Can I append processed chunks to a single target file on disk. How would the code above look? Could you help please?

Comment: what kind of file? You already have a single CSV file.

Comment: A new CSV file. If it is possible to append to a new parquet file, would be great to see that too!

Answer (score 3):

You can to read the chunks using:

```py
for df in pd.read_csv("path_to_file",  chunksize=chunksize):
  process(df)
```

The size of the chunks is related to your data. For instance, if your file has 4GB and 10 samples(rows) and you define the chunksize as 5, each chunk will have ~2GB and 5 samples.

You can analyze a file format too, [the `parquet` format has better compression power than `CSV`](https://blog.cloudera.com/benchmarking-apache-parquet-the-allstate-experience).

Comment: Cool, so how would the actual code look like for saving chunks to a single parquet file from a read/chunked 4GB csv file with a 100000 rows?

Comment: You can export each chunks to parquet, `df.to_parquet("path_to_file")`, and after exports, you would make a merge between the files.